# Best way to write this in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How do I refactor this in LINQ. I am working towards embracing good coding practices. My tds object looks like this: 
         tds -> BuildingName(List) -> buildingFloor(string) 
What I am accomplishing with the nested foreach loop is reading the buildingFloors into a list.

```
List<string> bname = new List<string>();

foreach (var building in tds) {
    foreach (var x in building.BuildingName) {
        bname.Add(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Linq have to do with good coding practices? What _specifically_ are you trying to do? Can you explain in words what this code does, and what have you tried to translate it to Linq?

Comment: I understand that Linq is a bit faster, inside the building there is a collection of buildingFloors that I am converting into a list.

Comment: LINQ is often considered to be more readable, as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) which will flatten your items

```
List<string> bname = tds.SelectMany(b => b.BuildingName).ToList();
```

Comment: When I run this line through the debugger, I get   bname The name 'bname' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: did you replace whole code (including list creation) with this?

Comment: was `bname` declared/created somewhere earlier and not exactly like in the question?

Comment: No, I wish that was the problem.

Comment: do you get the error on line from my answer or somewhere else?

Comment: it comes from your answer

Comment: the only thing that could cause this error on my line would be if you copied only `bname = ...` instead of whole `List<string> bname = ...` or, also valid, `var bname = ...`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to flatten your list like:

```
List<string> bname = tds.SelectMany(r=> r.BuildingName).ToList();
```

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why did you use 'r' as your lambda variable?

Comment: @JoePhilllips, Since I started using LINQ back in 2008/2009, Early examples had `r`, *may be for record*, that is why I use this all the time.

Comment: Gotcha. To me it makes more sense to use 'b' since that variable represents the building name

Comment: With LINQ to SQL, I always thought of usages of r as 'row'

Comment: @JoePhilllips, yes I think this habit has come from early usage of LINQ to SQL, Have to overcome it someday :)(

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is SelectMany.

```
var bname = buildings.SelectMany(b => b.BuildingName);
```

Note, if you're going to be enumerating over the result multiple times with *foreach* then you will probably want to ToList() it, so you have a hard list rather than an enumerable that is executed every time you enumerate it.

```
var bname = buildings.SelectMany(b => b.BuildingName).ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted me, but if you can explain why that'd be greatly appreciated since other, identical answers have been upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

something like this I suppose:

```
var bname = tds.SelectMany(x => x.BuildingName);
```

And if you need a List call `.ToList()` at the end

Comment: this will not return List<string>

Answer (score 1):

```
var bname = tds.Select( x=> x.buildingName).ToList() ;
```

edit: I did not see the inner foreach while on my commute to work, it is indeed

```
var bname = tds.SelectMany(x=> x.BuildingName).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess SelectMany could be better choice here

Comment: That is what I get for reading the post on my phone. SelectMany is correct, I did not see the inner loop. I have edited my response.

Answer (score 1):

using query-syntax:

```
List<string> bname =
  (from building in tds
  from x in building.BuildingName
  select x)
  .ToList()
```